# Databinding a check box

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, dataset

I have a check box that I binded with a dataset in its properties on my main form. Then on a separate form I have a datagrid that would be the options for each checkbox for a client. The datagrid is good when I look at it. but when I search for a client in the main form sometimes my checkboxes(some of them) will be selected for no reason. I have no coding for this as its all done in the properties except my search button.

```vb
Private Sub CmdSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CmdSearch.Click
    Dim iReturn As String
    Dim ClientFound As Boolean
    Looking = True
    ClientFound = False
    Place = ClientBindingSource.Position
    If Len(TxtSearch.Text) = 6 Then
        ClientBindingSource.MoveFirst()
        Do Until ClientFound = True
            With ClientBindingSource
                If Trim(TxtClient.Text) = TxtSearch.Text Then
                    If TxtSearch.Text = Trim(TxtClient.Text) Then
                        ClientFound = True
                    Else
                        ClientFound = False
                    End If
                    Place = ClientBindingSource.Position
                    Looking = False
                    Call LRSearch()
                    ClientBindingSource.Position = Place
                    Exit Sub
                ElseIf Trim(TxtClient.Text) = "ZZTEST" Then
                    iReturn = MsgBox(TxtSearch.Text & " Not Found", vbOKOnly)
                    ClientBindingSource.MoveFirst()
                    Looking = False
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    .MoveNext()
                End If
            End With
        Loop
    Else
        iReturn = MsgBox("Please check your client code for errors " & TxtSearch.Text, vbOKOnly)
        TxtSearch.Text = ""
    End If
    Looking = False
End Sub
```

I am not sure why the check boxes on my main form have a mind of their own?

Comment: `I am not sure why the check boxes on my main form have a mind of their own?` they don't, it is your mind translated to your program's logic.

Comment: Yes I know, just not sure what I did wrong